# What is My Rank On Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, reputation-leagues, user-rank

How do I know my rank among all Stack Overflow users?

Where can I see a list of top users according to their rank on Stack Overflow?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

Comment: @JamesAllardice: your rank is #392.

Comment: And you are #51260

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: that's not mine, I am not able to see my rank :(

Comment: @JAVAGeek. [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137994/173320)

Comment: Your meta profile is not associated with your SO profile, so we can't see for ourselves. Can you give us a link to your profile on SO?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill. But it does... read my answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd. Where did you get this number from? he's not ranked at all!

Comment: @gdoron -- indeed, although I thought from his comment above that he meant the "JAVAGeek" account on SO is not him, since the accounts aren't associated. But *duh*, they have the same gravatar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1485216/javageek

Comment: Ooops! I saw user [with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1399539/javageek) - sorry. ( @gdoron )

Comment: What's the purpose behind your last (and wrong) edit?

Comment: @hims056 i thought website is `stackoverflow` and not `stack overflow`.

Comment: @JAVAGeek - CrisF edited it. Didn't you see that? `Stack Overflow` is standard name. Don't mix both words.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your current reputation at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485216/javageek) is **155**
You can't see your rank because:

> - users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

When you pass 200 points you can see your rank [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow):

Comment: Now i can't even upvote your answer because it requires 15 rep and mine is only 9 on meta

Comment: @JAVAGeek. Well... It's not that important, anyway getting 6 points isn't that hard. `:)`

Comment: Nice! I wonder what determines inner ranking when the reputation score is the same? For example, why [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/190321/wt-w) is one before last and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/319912/hehewaffles) is last? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd. The amazing coincidental of random...? Just like with every sorting, the one you got first from the DB is before the later unless they have higher rank. I can't think of other option.

Comment: It is not showing mine reputation. It is 340. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2286243/varunagw

Answer (score 29):

A TLDR, simple answer:

Go to this [StackExchange Data Explorer Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379213/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile), provide your userid (clip it from your profile url on the site) and a Reputation Cutoff, and you'll see where you rank (in terms of the top N percent, as opposed to percentile rank discussed further below).

Interesting cutoffs:

- 1 - Rank vs All users
- 200 - Rank vs those tracked in the friendly rankings.
- 10,000 - Perhaps apochryphal, but reputedly a point where recruiters take an interest in users.

---

More involved/complicated answer:

To find your percentile rank amongst all Stackoverflow users with rep over 200 (which I find to be the most interesting figure), go to

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

and note your rank. Then look at the total reputation table, and note the number of users with rep at 200+. Then calculate, for example in Python:

```
def my_percentile_rank(my_rank, users):
    my_percentile = int((1-my_rank/float(users))*100)
    print('My rank is in the {0} percentile'.format(my_percentile))    
    return my_percentile

my_rank = 20927 # on 3/3/2014
users = 168795

my_percentile_rank(my_rank, users)
```

Which prints for me,

```
My rank is in the 87 percentile
```

And if you have a goal for your percentile, find the 99th percentile cutoff (currently the 99th percentile reputation is 24,531, and the cutoff is rank ~1687. )

```
percentile = users * .01
```

And your current reputation target is, based on your desired percentile:

```
my_target_percentile = 90
my_reputation_target_rank = (100 - my_target_percentile)*percentile
```

So my target rank to be in the 90th percentile is 16879.5

A convenience function to show multiple ranks required:

```
def target_ranks(users, ps=None):
    percentile = users * .01
    if ps == None:
        ps = 25, 50, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
    import pprint
    results = dict((p, (100-p) * percentile) for p in ps)
    print('the rank (not rep) required for percentiles:')
    pprint.pprint(results)
    return results
```

To quickly find where the 16879.5 ranking is, skip to find the user with the one percentile ranking and their reputation (currently the 34th page in, I got there by browsing in a few pages and then editing the url).

Multiply that page number (including the decimal fraction for how far down the page) by the number of percentiles below 100 to quickly find page with the rep for the ranking you desire. so (34.5-1) * 10 is 335 pages in (but I have to browse over to 338).

And I find that the cutoff for my target percentile is currently 3,569.

Since everyone's rep is constantly growing and StackOverflow is getting new users over our 200 cutoff, that's a moving target, so I need to aim beyond that, probably setting a mental goal of 4000 rep points so I can safely say I'm in the 90th percentile of users with rep over 200.

Comment: haha such an overkill but yeah +1 ;)

Comment: @mehow I keep referring back to it, because it makes the calculating so easy, 89th percentile now! :)

Comment: I beat 3500, but now the 90th %ile is at 3572... well, 89th percentile is good! :)

Comment: Just hit 3584! I'm in the top 10% of 200+ rep users!

Comment: 3571 is the 90th percentile mark now, 95th percentile is 6621 rep

Comment: 92nd%ile at 4445!

Comment: Current 95th %ile of 200+ rep users is rank 8669 and rep 6626. I'm currently at rank 12753 and rep 4786, at about 92.6%, still in 92nd %ile.

Comment: Just hit 5000, taking a bit of a break from obsessively interacting with the site, after hitting 200+ in one day. I have a wife, a job, and a cat, and I'm putting more time into technology training. Maybe I'll show up for a few hours here and there, but not right now.

Comment: Just hit 6576, 70 rep shy of the 95th percentile (currently 6646)... Nice. I'll tweet when I hit it, maybe late tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Just hit 6659. 95th %ile! Tweeting!

Comment: still at 95th percentile at 7190 rep, 96th percentile is currently 8108 rep, so maybe I'll shoot for that. Maybe then 97th, 98th, 99th... nah, probably not.

Comment: right now, these percentiles apply to the following ranks: 96: 7521.6, 97: 5641.2, 98: 3760.8, 99: 1880.4 and their respective reps are currently: 96: 8,108, 97: 10,428, 98: 14,625, 99: 24,660.

Comment: I'm currently at 10130, 97th percentile rep is currently 10539. 98 is 14718, 99 is 24972...

Comment: 97th %ile rank is 6328.17 - rep 10,533, 98: 4218.78 - rep 14,702, 99: 2109.39 - rep 25,053. My current rep is 10561. I'm declaring myself inside the 97th %ile for 2014!

Comment: At over 15000, I'm now in the 98th %ile and thus the top 2%, as of a few days ago.

Comment: Interesting to note that, compared to when I started this, cutoff for the top 1% is about 2280 and rep is 25,280.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to pass the 200 reputation mark before your reputation is comparable to the likes of the Skeet and co.

If you go to your profile page (click your username in the top nav) and click the link displayed in the image below:[image]

If you want to access it quickly now, you can use this [link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). But for future reference use the highlighted method above.

Comment: have you exposed your personal details on purpose?

Comment: I don't mind people knowing my email address and real name.

Answer (score 10):

The [Stack Exchange leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) allows you to see all users, sorted by reputation over various time periods (week, month, quarter, year and all time), with your own profile placed nicely at the top. For example, if I select "All Time", I currently see this:

[image]

You can see the lists for all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Note that it also notes on that page:

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

That's why you are not able to see yourself in the list yet.

Comment: Strange.. i can't see my profile on top.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It says on the page that "users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues".

Comment: ohh.. that's the reason..

Comment: @JamesAllardice It is not showing mine reputation. It is 340. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2286243/varunagw

Answer (score 0):

You can see this using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer with this query:
[StackOverflow Rank and Percentile](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile)

You only need to specify your user ID which you can find in the URL when visiting your profile page on the site you're running the query on.